# Using the #import directive on a microsoft shared dll

Tags: c++, com

I do not have much experience working with COM and was wondering if anyone knew the minimum amount of information I have to provide to #import a dll into a cpp file (which will be used to make a dll). According to MDSN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6(v=vs.80).aspx) I need to include a type library resource such as an .ocx file. Is this the case even for a Microsoft shared dll (e.g. mso.dll)? In addition, what are the other type library resources can I use?

From what I have gathered so far, I just need to provide enough information to the MIDL for it to form the interface to the dll in the right way (this seems to be the essence of COM).

---

The original link is dead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp?view=vs-2019 seems to be the new URL.

Comment: The MSDN documentation for the #import directive is good for any type library, provided by Microsoft or not. Some DLLs/OCXs have TLB embedded in it, some others don't. #import does work with mso.dll, for example: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259298/en-us

Comment: So if the dll does not embed TLB then are you saying that #import does not work? Or does this simply reduce the work for the compiler? How is TLB embedded into the dll's by the way?

Comment: It is not.  You must run Tlbexp.exe to generate the type library from the .NET assembly.  Which you can then #import.

Comment: Which only works on .net assemblies. So trying to import the dll (mso.dll) alone should not work (it doesn't at present and I am trying to determine the reason/understand COM better)?

Comment: Importing mso alone does work. Just declare this `#import "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE15\mso.dll"` (adapt to your Office path)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that was the first thing I tried and expected it to work but the intellisense was complaining about the lack of a .tlh file in the visual studio folder. I like to have the complete picture which is why I posted this question. I will have another look at this tomorrow since I am not on the network at present and it could well be I have made some boneheaded mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In the link that you listed a key sentence is "#import creates two header files that reconstruct the type library contents in C++ source code". When you #import MSO.DLL you are importing a type library to your project (not to your cpp file) and it creates the necessary COM interface definitions. So you don't need to provide additional information.

But there are probably other files you need to #import in order to use Office applications, depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: "into a cpp file" sorry, slip of the tongue, was trying to convey I would be using the defined quantities in my cpp file, but you're right not strictly correct to say this.

Comment: That sentence about #import creating header files would be on successful execution of the #import though or at least that is how I read it. I mean what if the dll was compiled in C (no name mangling) how would the compiler extract interface information from exported functions?